# How to make changes in flutter plugins code locally

Tags: flutter, dart

flutter_keyboard_visibility is giving me null Activity error that is crashing my application when running in the background.I have to add checks in that plugin code. Where can I find that plugin code is that in flutter folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

External libraries -> Flutter Plugins

[image]

I think, you can find it here

But I wouldn't recommend to edit this plugin here. It'd be better to copy it in your project and edit after this

Comment: I want to change it locally

Comment: where locally i can find tht file

Comment: As I've said - External libraries -> Flutter Plugins

Comment: I've added screenshot

Answer (score 3):

All your packages are stored at `<FLUTTER_SDK>/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/<your_package_name>`

> HERE THE EXAMPLE IS WITH `esys_flutter_share`

You have to copy that code from there and paste in root directory of your current project as shown in screenshot.

[image]

Now edit your `pubspec.yaml` as shown below

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.6.1"
  esys_flutter_share:
    path: ./esys_flutter_share-1.0.1
  photo_manager:
    path: ./photo_manager-0.3.4
```

> Now you can edit the code of your custom package the way you want.